# Update fields inside v-for loop using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How can i update multiple fields inside the v-for loop using Vue.js,as i have fields which i iterate using v-for loop and want to update any field.
besides this i am able to delete and add new fields successfully.

Here what i am trying to do

**Note**:i can update fields with static values,but needs to update it with real values.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {

    users: [{
      name: 'test',
      phone: '1234'
    }, ],
    form: {
      name: '',
      phone: ''
    },
    show_link: true,
    IsOn: false,
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      this.IsOn = true
      this.show_link = false
    },
    removeSelected(index) {
      this.users.splice(index, 1);
    },
    saveForm() {
      this.users.push({

        name: this.form.name,
        phone: this.form.phone
      })
      this.form.name = '';
      this.form.phone = '';

    },
    updateForm(key) {
      this.users[key].name = 'john doe', // should be the entered value
        this.users[key].phone = '0000' // should be the entered value
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(user,key) in users">
      <label>
        <input type="text" v-model="user.name">
        <input type="text" v-model="user.phone">
        <input type="button" value="Update" @click="updateForm(key)">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" @click="removeSelected(key)">
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>

  <a v-if="show_link" @click="addRow">Add Another</a>


  <div v-if="IsOn">
    <hr />


    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="form.name">
    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="form.phone">
    <input type="button" value="Save" @click="saveForm">

  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: typical reactivity issue. use this.$set for setting nested object values. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set . See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad

Comment: Thank you,looking into it @JacobGoh